# Why window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) does not work

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, frontend, addeventlistener

I have created a simple idea of Hangman game, which runs on console. Everything works, but when I try to use window.addEventListener('keypress, function(e) I cannot press the characters for the game.

```js
const Hangman = function(word, remainguess) {
  this.word = word.toLowerCase().split('')
  this.remainguess = remainguess
  this.guessedLetters = []
}

Hangman.prototype.getPuzzle = function() {
  let puzzle = ' '
  this.word.forEach(element => {
    if (this.guessedLetters.includes(element) || element === ' ') {
      puzzle += element
    } else {
      puzzle += '*'


    }

  });
  return puzzle

}
Hangman.prototype.guessing = function(guess) {
  guess = guess.toLowerCase()
  const isUnique = !this.guessedLetters.includes(guess)
  const isBaddGuess = !this.word.includes(guess)
  if (isUnique) {
    this.guessedLetters.push(guess)
  }

  if (isBaddGuess) {
    this.remainguess--
  }
  // return this.remainguess
}
const game1 = new Hangman('cat', 1)

window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  const guess = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)
  game1.guessing(guess)
  console.log(game1.getPuzzle())
  console.log(game1.remainguess)
})
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: You're not doing anything with your `guess` except logging it's value to the console.

Comment: `keypress` doesn't register all the characters you can enter from the keyboard.

Comment: I cannot press the charcters anything in the keyboard of the console, using that function, that is what I mean @hev1